# C++/CLI: Passing structures from c# to managed c++ DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli, managed-c++

I have been looking around but couldn't find a solution to my problem.
I have a static library (.lib) written in pure C, with the header file (.h), I want to use this library in a c# project, so what I did is creating a new CLR project to make a wrapper for my static library. 
My question is about types and arguments, for many functions I need to use a structure defined in C like that:

```
typdef struct
{   int number;
    int index;
} myRef;
```

Here is the prototype of my function in the header file:

```
int IndexToRef(int index, myRef* reef);
```

In my dll wrapper I have the following:

wrappper.h

```
namespace wrapper
{
    public ref class myWrapperClass
    {
        public:
            int w_IndexToRef(int index, myRef* reef);
    }
}
```

wrapper.cpp

```
using namespace wrrapper;

int myWrapperClass::w_IndexToRef(int index, myRef* reef)
{
    return IndexToRef(index, reef);
}
```

This code compiles, I get a nice dll, I use it as a reference in my c# project, but when I call this function with the same structure using the ref keyword, I get the error

> "cannot convert from ref to *"

.

How can I pass a structure from C# to a managed DLL?

Comment: myRef is an *unmanaged* type and thus not usable from C#.  You need to declare an equivalent `value struct`.

Comment: Thank you, I see what you mean. @HansPassant